# Licensing checker longevity of the "activated" status. How frequent is too much for the user?

Tags: android, android-lvl

My app is a kind of a pocket guide with some data for the whole year. I'm assuming users will use the program at least once with Internet access to activate the license. Or at least that's my understanding of how the Android licensing system works. I'm using ServerManagedPolicy.

Does it check periodically for the license? Is there any way that I can control this? I don't want my users to be in the middle of nowhere, with an app already and previously activated and suddenly after 1 week, 1 month, 1 year etc. the app starts limiting the usability of the app itself because the license couldn't be verified *again*. My app is going to be used in remote places with erratic net access (can't be taken for granted all the time) by people who will live there for weeks, maybe months.

I feel I should at least warn them that they will be asked every X weeks to do that. Is the license system even that draconian?

I know I can handle the errors with the ERROR_CONTACTING_SERVER flag, on the applicationError void of LicenseCheckerCallback. Is the "VT" response always the same (can't test this on a test account/my account)? I was just curious about how you guys treat this situation on your own real life apps. Am I missing something here? For some reason I'm feeling I am. Is there any "catch"?

***// EDITED:***

Here is the code I'm trying right now:

```
// ServerManagedPolicy.java
private void setValidityTimestamp(String validityTimestamp) {
    Long lValidityTimestamp;
    try {
        lValidityTimestamp = Long.parseLong(validityTimestamp);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // No response or not parsable, expire in one minute.
        Log.w(TAG, "License validity timestamp (VT) missing, caching for a minute");
        lValidityTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() + MILLIS_PER_MINUTE;
        validityTimestamp = Long.toString(lValidityTimestamp);
    }
    // added by me--->

    private static long maxLicense = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 30; // ~ roughly 30 days
    private static long minLicense = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 3;  // ~ roughly 3 days

    long lMax = System.currentTimeMillis() + maxLicense;
    long lMin = System.currentTimeMillis() + minLicense;
    if ((lValidityTimestamp > lMin) && (lValidityTimestamp < lMax)) {
        validityTimestamp = Long.toString(lMax);
    }

    // <--- added by me

    mValidityTimestamp = lValidityTimestamp;
    mPreferences.putString(PREF_VALIDITY_TIMESTAMP, validityTimestamp);
}
```

Comment: you have read http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html?

Comment: The question here is not if I've read. It's how many times I did. Inclusing all related blog entries by Tim Bray, Dan Galpin and Trevor Johns. :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just my two cents, you can define a period of time you would like to check (lets say 3 days). Check for the license after 3 days, if there is no internet, continue letting the user use it for lets say another week max or else the app will not be full functioned. Or just keep it full functioned until there is a connection again, then you can check and reset your time stamp. The license checker will only check when you tell it to.

I can clarify if need be!

Good luck

Comment: It's a very good policy, actually. You even got me wondering if this would be the best case. I could let the users use the app for a week, which is definitely AFTER the refund period, even if just guessing the normal "VT"s. And after that period, use the Internet on the first opportunity to activate the app and write the custom VT to preferences for 30 or 40 days as I want. Oh well, if only Google would have a more customizable LVL library... I will see what I can do. I know it sounds simple, but my question was simple I guess. You provided me the "insight" I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I just take it from there (what you proposed) and implement the long VT. Sometimes two cents is all we need.

Answer (score 2):

David, the short answer is it is up to you.

Taken directly from the developer document. "For example, the server provides recommended values for the application's license validity period, retry grace period, and maximum allowable retry count, among others."

Depending how you choose to implement the policy, your choosing the answer to your own question.

Comment: I see, thanks. But my point is... how do I do that? Even better: what's the recommended way? Right now, this is what I'm doing... I modified the ServerManagedPolicy class, in "setValidityTimestamp". If lValidityTimestamp is bigger than 3 days from now or smaller than 1 month from now (I get this using System.currenttimemillis), I automatically set the lValidityTimestamp to 1 month. For now, this is what I'm trying... I can't say for sure because the test accounts don't receive the "extras" VT etc.

Comment: The logic behind that is that I'm trying to only "interfere" on the default stuff if it's bigger than the refund period (3 days more than enough) or smaller than 1 month. For now, I'm testing it... I want a minimum of 1 month of "worry-free" for my customers. I'm guessing that the market may return more than 1 month, which is even better for me and my customers. But as I said, I'm blind with test accounts. Do you think it will work? I think I will post my code for you to see.

Comment: Well, you could do two things.  One, validate what you can using the test response from a publisher account.  Two, take a look at the sample implementation application (I believe this comes with the LVL download) and compare the implementations.  All you really need to do is look at the response you get and handle it appropriately for whatever you want to happen.  I'm not quite sure why it would matter what is returned in the validity timestamp as long as you handle it appropriately on your end.

Comment: I see... that's what I'm doing. But the response I get is not real. For publisher and test accounts, we get a null extra with no validity timestamp ("VT" field). And that's why the implementation sets a "1 minute" default if it gets a LicenseResponse.LICENSED with no extra fields. I was just asking what you guys ideas on what I should do (general ideas, insights. I get the meaning of the code... I've read the licensing package and classes many times already, I know how it works) since I can't test the VT that my users will get. I hope you understand. Continue next...

Comment: Practical points: generally, how long is the VT for regular users (isn't it amusing that the Market requires us to buy our own apps in order to test them on a real scenario)? I must know that (even if just an average) if I want to change the policy efficiently. Also... do I need to (can I? should I?) overwrite for a longer VT if the VT received (see code) is less than the refund period? Should I even care? What I I grant a generous policy in the refund period (again, can't test real VT responses), and my users end with a 1 month license on a refunded app? Those are doubts I have. Thanks.

Comment: Let me stress this: I've read the package. I know *exactly* how the LVL classes works. I know exactly the license policy I want, but see above. Hey, I also heavily modified it to most of my needs. I actually deployed my app already on the Market. But not all is clear.

Comment: Just another comment.  I spoke with an iPhone user this weekend.  He told me you can't return iPhone applications, which is true (without a formal complaint to Apple).  If your willing to modify how you deal with returns (just use Google's built in policy), it sounds like you could save yourself a big headache while still maintaining a policy that the vast majority of your users expect.  I mean...is your app's selling point really the fact you can return it 30 days later?

Comment: This is not what I want and not what the code above does. I want to implement a policy that: 1) allow legitimate users to use the app for 30 or 40 days without needing to periodically re-check the license; 2) stay in conformity with the Market refund policy. The 2 is the main challenge because I can't test it. With 2, I may risk this: buy->activate for 30 or 40 days->refund in the next 24/48/etc hours->still have the licensed information on cache. That's why I was asking what is the default "validity timestamp" bahavior.

Answer (score 1):

Even with the ServerManagedPolicy, your app will *only* check for a license when you call "checkAccess()" as described in the [checking access](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#check-access) section of the licensing doc.  If that call is never made, your app will continue to work indefinitely - As such, if you can detect that your users are in a situation where they legitimately cannot ping the server for license information, you can wrap the "checkAccess" call in a condition for that.

Further down the page there's information on setting up test accounts to verify LVL functionality.  I *highly* recommend making good use of that testing functionality.

Comment: Look, I really appreciate your time coming here to answer, don't take me wrong... but of course I'm testing it with test accounts. And I know I can just *not* call checkAccess... after all, that's what I was doing when I didn't have any license mechanism to begin with :). My question here is about the longevity of the received answer by the Market license... how long I need to wait... how much is the "VT" field on the real world. You probably know by now that any test account will have a signal that expires the response in 1 minute or so. Testing accounts don't answer this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to this very simply.  Connect a real device via USB to your computer.  Edit your LVL library source code in ServerManagedPolicy.java and add in a log statement for the lValidityTimestamp variable using DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM,DateFormat.MEDIUM).  Then uninstall your application to clear out any previous license cache timestamp, reinstall, and run your app.  This contacts the server and then your logging statement reveals the answer.  In my testing, the VT comes back to be exactly 1 day from now (when the license is checkes).

Comment: Could you elaborate on that answer? Here I get 1 minute, as expected from the code above. Second, are you trying with a test account or not? What are you debugging? If it's your app, how do you not get the standard "1 minute" response? Because I assume that you are not editing the source of other apps (in other words, disassembling) in order to include the Log, to test it. Very good answer, but now I have even more questions.